# compiling cmocka with the xc8 compiler from microchip howto?

Tags: c, testing, xc8, cmocka

Good afternoon devs,

When I checkout the latest cmocka version and try to compile cmocka with the xc8 compiler version 1.41 the code wont compile syntaxis error.

It isnt recommend or the solution to change this cmocka source, because in the future when a new cmocka version is out. its not nice to have to change that file again.

So the requirement is a solution without changing the cmocka code.

Or is this totally wrong thinking, it would be nice if you devs can push me in a direction for this.

Update:

```
include\cmocka.h: 256: (163) unexpected text in control line ignored (warning)
include\cmocka.h: 1645: (112) #define syntax error (error)
include\cmocka.h: 1645: (163) unexpected text in control line ignored (warning)
```

the messages, but when I removed this code, it would error out on like 500 more errors.